# How to make android build in expo project with android folder present in the project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

While creating a android build in expo project I got two error

Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io, *.pe.jfrog.io]

Certificate for <google.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io, *.pe.jfrog.io]

How can I resolve the above errors[image]